# Desenvolver aplicativo compatível com Windows 10 e Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uwp

Estou trabalhando em uma aplicação que utilizamos o Windows Forms para desenvolver a sua versão alpha. Em breve, iniciaremos o desenvolvimento de uma versão mais estável deste sistema, e,  foi então que as plataformas de suporte  se tornaram o centro de nossas discussões.

Temos o desejo de enviar o sistema para o Windows Store, e também queremos dar suporte ás versões **8, 8.1 e 10** do Windows. Como ainda sou novo quando o assunto é desenvolvimento para mobile/desktop, fiz uma breve pesquisa sobre as opções de desenvolvimento em que resultaria no melhor aproveitamento de código.
Infelizmente não encontrei nenhuma solução viável até  o momento.

Posso utilizar o Universal Windows Platform para desenvolver um sistema com suporte a estas versões do Windows?

Existe algum padrão de projeto ou padrão de *layout* exigido para desenvolver um aplicativo que será enviado para a Windows Store?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O Universal Windows Platform só funciona nessas versões. Não funciona em versões anteriores.

Se deseja mesmo colocar na Windows Store é praticamente sua única opção. Até [já é possível usar aplicações antigas (Win32) na Windows Store](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop), mas não é o ideal, só vale a pena fazer isto em aplicações legadas. Não comece algo novo para colocar na WS em tecnologias que usam a Win32 diretamente.

Mas pense se realmente é importante colocar na WS. Se não for pode fazer em WinForms ou WPF. Aí atende Windows 7 e até anteriores, ainda que eles não são mais suportados.

Mesmo que só queira essas versões mais novas pode haver vantagens em fazer com essas tecnologias mais antigas (sim, ela tem vantagens em relação à mais nova, assim como tem desvantagens também). Mas aí eu nem me preocuparia em colocar no WS.

Mas tudo isto é muito abstrato. Só você pode saber o que é mais adequado para este projeto. E como está perguntando você também não sabe. Complicou.

Existem padrões que devem ser seguidos, mas é muita coisa para postar aqui, mas tudo dentro da normalidade.

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/store-policies?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397

Comment: Obrigado, vou considerar melhor as opções/objetivos do sistema